# Include before join Doesn't work Entity Framework 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, lazy-loading, entity-framework-6

In an MVC4 project
I use include in a LINQ query:

```
> var tests = from ct in context.CourseTest.Include("Test")  join uc in
> context.UserCourse on ct.CourseID equals uc.CourseID select ct;
```

CourseTest has a Test Object

This works inside the "using context"

but once returned to the controller using:

return tests.ToList();

the

UserCourse.Test is being disposed:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used
>   for operations that require a connection.

This used to work fine in older version (not sure if I tested it with the join).

How can I make it stick.. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes, the include clause is ignored. I've not all the case in my head but joining, grouping and projecting entities will cause EF to ignore includes.

In your example, if you do :

```
var Tests = from ct in context.CourseTest join uc in context.UserCourse on ct.CourseID equals uc.CourseID select ct; 
return Tests.Include("Test").ToList();
```

That will works because the include is not overriden by a projection, a grouping or a joining clause.

Just another things :

1/ is your joining clause really usefull ? (only if you want the course test that muse have a user course.)

2/ for your disposed context, it's because your DbContext use lazy loading. Your include clause is ignored but with lazy loading, instead of null, your test navigation property contains a proxy (i.e. is not null). So when you access your navigation property, the proxy see that the real data is not loaded and performs a query to get the Test data. Your context is disposed so you have your exception.

EF generate query but execute the query only when iterating the result (in a foreach loop or with ToList(), ToArray(), ToDictionary(), ... ) So if you a data access layer with use a using clause for your context, always be sure to iterate your result in order to make EF execute the query (with a ToList() for example).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use a Singleton implementation of the context. Then it should not be disposed (but has other disadvantages, like: only one context which is not disposed).

Comment: singleton contexts are dangerous!! it has concurrency issues.